# react-redux- issue with dispatching actions

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to dispatch to my redux store that was configured using configureStore.

```
const store = configureStore({reducer: {
    account: accountReducer,
    auth: authReducer
}});
```

My "accountReducer" looks like this:

```
const initialState = {
  accountInfo: {}
};

export const accountReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  console.log(action.type);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_ACCOUNT_INFO":
        return {
            ...state,
            accountInfo: action.payload
        };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And this is the code that's supposed to dispatch the action "GET_ACCOUNT_INFO":

```
export const getAccountInfo = () => async (dispatch) => {
  var accountInfo = {};

  const token = localStorage.jwtToken;
  setAuthToken(token);

  const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
  const currentUsername = decoded.name;
  await fetch(`${Globals.API_URL}/account/info/?username=${currentUsername}`, { headers: { "x-access-token": token }})
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => 
    {
      if(data.message != null)
      {
        accountInfo = {message: data.message};
      } else {
        accountInfo = data;
      }
      dispatch({
        type: "GET_ACCOUNT_INFO",
        payload: data
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch({
        type: "GET_ERRORS",
        payload: error
      });
    })
}
```

I tried using useDispatch() in my component, and this shows up in the console:

```
@@redux/INIT0.a.n.8.r.6.r    accountReducer.js:6 
@@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION7.g.x.b.i.k    accountReducer.js:6 
@@redux/INIT0.a.n.8.r.6.r    accountReducer.js:6
```

How do I make it so the action type is "GET_ACCOUNT_INFO" instead of this weird string?

Answer (score 0):

Those are internal actions that the Redux store dispatches on startup to initialize the state. You can and should ignore those.

Also, note that while you're correctly using the modern `configureStore` API from Redux Toolkit to set up the store, your reducers are written using the old and discouraged hand-written approach.  Instead, you should be using the `createSlice` API from Redux Toolkit:

```
const initialState = {
  accountInfo: {}
};

const accountsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "accounts",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    accountInfoLoaded(state, action) {
      state.accountInfo = action.payload;
    }
  }
})
```

For that matter, you could replace the hand-written account fetching thunk with RTK's `createAsyncThunk`.

Please see the Redux Essentials tutorial in our docs for more details:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure